# Data loss handling when using user-defined conversion. C#

Tags: c#, casting

For educational purposes I do lots of things (that maybe never used) with casting. One of them lead me to solution that I dislike.

Let's say, I have 2 classes:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int MyInt;
    public string MyString;
}

class ClassB
{
    public int SomeInt;
}
```

Now I want implicitly cast ClassA to ClassB. To do that I can write:

```
public static implicit operator ClassB(ClassA obj1)
{
    ClassB obj2 = new ClassB();
    obj2.SomeInt = obj1.MyInt;

    return obj2;
}
```

But there's a possibility that `MyString` get lost, that must not be allowed. To solve this problem I've added to my conversion:

```
if (obj1.MyString != null)
   throw new DataLostException();
```

This works fine, but there must be simpler solution. My question is, How can I handle this kind of data loss in a simpler way?

Comment: what do you mean "in a simpler way"?

Comment: Well where do you think the string value will go ? not sure what you are trying to do, an example would be great to have

Comment: @V4Vendetta It's just for educational purposes, not real project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  Such data loss is the "default behavior" when creating a user defined conversion operator, which is a relatively advanced use of the language.

There is no inheritance relation between the two classes, and there is no way for the framework to know how that string might relate to the other class.  Who knows, it might be a piece of diagnostic information that is completely unnecessary in the new context.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively doing what I'd call an upcast, but without the regular inheritance model (as a regular upcast would be B extends A). Upcasts can lead to data being narrower in scope. If you upcast to a less featured class then you expect that you will have less information, that's just how it works. You don't care about mystring if you're using class A as class a has no mystring.